# TreeMap returns null while using map.get(Object)

Tags: java, collections, treemap

***TreeMap*** prints value as null while fetching value using get method whereas it is working fine with `HashMap()`. Please find below the sample code and provide inputs to this.

It's working fine for Hashmap as it uses `equals()/hashcode()` methods whereas TreeMap are SortedMap, it doesn't use equals method to compare two objects. Instead, it uses **comparator/comparable** to compare the objects but while fetching the object using get method, it's giving null as response. Please provide some clarity here.

```
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Map.Entry;
    import java.util.TreeMap;

    class Employees implements Comparable<Employees>, Comparator<Employees> {

        public Employees(String name, int id) {
            super();
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String name;
    private int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof Employees))
            return false;
        Employees other = (Employees) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employees o) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Employees o1, Employees o2) {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class Employee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Map<Employees, Integer> m = new HashMap<>(); // equals will be used here.
        Map<Employees, Integer> m = new TreeMap<Employees, Integer>(); // no equals/hashcode used here as we use comparator/comparable to compare objects.
        Employees e1 = new Employees("abc", 11);
        Employees e2 = new Employees("abc", 12);
        System.out.println(m.put(e1, 1));
        System.out.println(m.put(e2, 2));
        **System.out.println(m.get(e2));**
    }
}
```

Comment: TreeMap's get(..) method uses compareTo method, you allway return 1; you should remove @Override compareTo method, then try again.

Comment: very good question...:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `compareTo` method always returns `1`, which means no `Employees` object is equal to any other `Employees` object (not even to itself) as far as `compareTo` is concerned.

Only when `compareTo` returns `0` the two compared instances are considered identical by `TreeMap`.

BTW, your `hashCode` implementation of always returning `1` is also bad. While it works (for `HashMap`), it causes all the entries to be stored in the same bucket, which destroys the performance of the `HashMap`.

Comment: For completeness: [`Comparable::compareTo(T o)` defines its contract as follow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html): "*Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.*"